# Julia: how to get the first elements of a 2d array which are more than the elements of a vector?

Tags: julia

I have a 2d array defined like this:

```
> s = cumsum([0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4; 0.25 0.15 0.35 0.25; 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.1], dims=2)
3×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.1   0.3  0.6   1.0
 0.25  0.4  0.75  1.0
 0.3   0.6  0.9   1.0
```

And I define a random vector

```
> r = rand(3)
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.5560575798047342
 0.4759478853774721
 0.48545434824655853
```

I know that this line of code returns all elements of s which are more than the elements of r based on row-wise comparison

```
> s.*(r .< s)
3×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  0.0  0.6   1.0
 0.0  0.0  0.75  1.0
 0.0  0.6  0.9   1.0
```

But I need to get a solution like this

```
3×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  0.0  0.6   0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.75  0.0
 0.0  0.6  0.0   0.0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Julia: how to get the first elements of a 2d array which are more than the elements of a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63315063/julia-how-to-get-the-first-elements-of-a-2d-array-which-are-more-than-the-eleme)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some two approaches that you can consider are (I use the same `r` as you).

A simple one but a bit verbose:

```
julia> x = r .< s
3×4 BitArray{2}:
 0  0  1  1
 0  0  1  1
 0  1  1  1

julia> s .* [x[i, j] - (j == 1 ? 0 : x[i, j - 1]) for i in axes(x, 1), j in axes(x, 2)]
3×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  0.0  0.6   0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.75  0.0
 0.0  0.6  0.0   0.0
```

and a similar thing a bit shorter:

```
julia> using ShiftedArrays

julia> x = r .< s
3×4 BitArray{2}:
 0  0  1  1
 0  0  1  1
 0  1  1  1

julia> s .* coalesce.(x .- lag(x, (0, 1)), 0)
3×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  0.0  0.6   0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.75  0.0
 0.0  0.6  0.0   0.0
```

Comment: I think I just need to find the second smallest value in each row and change the values of all other non-zero elements to zero.

Comment: The rule you propose would be ambiguous if your original matrix (before `cumsum` contained `0` entries)